I have Unity Firebase Realtime Database question
Before start it, please understand I'm newbie
I coded it
    public void Start()
    {
        UserInformationRenewal();
    }

    public void UserInformationRenewal()
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference
            .Child("users")
            .Child(firebaseLogin.userId)
            .Child("received")
            .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
    }

    public void UserInformationReset()
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference
            .Child("users")
            .Child(firebaseLogin.userId)
            .Child("received")
            .ValueChanged -= HandleValueChanged;
    }

    void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        print("changed");
        if ((bool)args.Snapshot.Value == true) SocialNotification(true);
        else if ((bool)args.Snapshot.Value == false) SocialNotification(false);
    }

and UserInformationReset() doesn't work
(firebaseLogin.userId is "FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId;" and it works well)
I tried print("success") in UserInformationReset(), it printed "success" successfully but ValueChange event has not removed
and tried
    public void UserInformationReset()
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference
            .Child("users")
            .Child(firebaseLogin.userId)
            .Child("received")
            .SetValueAsync("test");
    }

then, "test" value set in "reveiced" successfully in Firebase Realtime Database
there's no error message

I'm assuming this happens when you're changing the logged in user. Are you sure that firebaseLogin.userId is still the old/previous user's UID when you call UserInformationReset? Otherwise you're trying to remove the listener from the new user, instead of the old one.

@puf-FrankvanPuffelen
oh, I'm sorry I haven't checked for a long time It was too busy to check it and thank you for replying to my question but firebaseLogin.userId is still the old/previous user's UID I tested it by print(firebaseLogin.userId), and it printed old/previous user's UID

Hmm... in that case I don't know what's happening. Hopefully somebody else spots it.

@puf-FrankvanPuffelen oh.. ok thanks for spending time to reply my question
